# Sonarqube 6.2 not assigning project to group when new project is created against a matching permissions template

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Using Sonarqube 6.2, I have setup a permissions template with a Project Key Pattern: 'generic\.*'.   That permssions template has a group that contains a user.
When I run sonarscan on a new project with sonar.projectKey=generic.org.sonarqube:parent2, the user can't see the project till I 'Apply Permissions Template' to that new project.
My understanding was that the [matching permissions template should be applied automatically](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authorization) on new project creation without an Admin user being required to apply the template manually through the UI ?

Answer (score 3):

As indicated in the UI when creating a *Permission Template*: the Project Key Pattern *should be a valid regular expression*.

So your problem seems to simply boil down to regex definition: `generic.org.sonarqube:parent2` does not fully match with`generic\.*` (see [online regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/A84upv/2)). You miss a dot before that trailing `*` in order to match 0 **or more characters** at the end.

All in all: try with `generic\..*` as regex.

Comment: Great thank you! and I'll test that as that is a problem.  Though I assumed it was OK since when I applied that template, the project showed up for that user when it shouldn't have given the regex being incorrect as you pointed out ?

Comment: The regex is only used for 'auto-applying' a template whenever a project is created. When you manually apply a template then there is no regex involved at all and the related permission scheme is applied. If this solved your issue then you should [accept this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: Great to know.  Thanks again!

Comment: @NicolasB.-SonarSourceTeam is it supposed to work for an existing project that is currently public? Let's say I have the following key in my projects: `my.company.section:APP<UNIQUE IDENTIFIER>` (eg: `my.company.section:APP1234`), I got the following regex (which is valid on regex101), but the permission template isn't being applied properly. Pattern is `my\.company\.section.\..*`

Answer (score 0):

Use `sonar.projectName=generic.org.sonarqube:parent2`. Otherwise, the permission template won't be applied with the first analysis creation.